# Normalization of an image dataset after processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

**Edited With More Clear Explanation**

I am trying to normalize images in a dataset after processing them, but min, max, ranges change (for example one image is between the range `[0.38,5.26]` and another one is `[-0.44, 3.65]`) after the processing and normalizing them between `[0,1]` with the common normalization approach but it causes inconsistency between images.

```
imagesPath = '/home/berkanhoke/Datasets/Freiburg/Org/Night/';
outFolderPath = '/home/berkanhoke/Datasets/Freiburg/Maddern/Night';
imageSet = dir(strcat(imagesPath,'*.jpeg'));
imageCount = length(imageSet);
for i = 1:imageCount
   fileName = imageSet(i).name;
   filePath = strcat(imagesPath,fileName);
   img = double(imread(filePath));
   I_old = maddern(img,0.3975);
   I_new = (I_old - min(I_old(:)))/(max(I_old(:)) - min(I_old(:)));
   writePath = strcat(outFolderPath,fileName);
   imwrite(I_new,writePath,'jpeg');
end
```

The function I use for processing is the following:

```
function [ ii_image ] = maddern( image, alpha )
ii_image = 0.5 + log(image(:,:,2)+1)...
         - alpha * log(image(:,:,3)+1)...
         - (1-alpha) * log(image(:,:,1)+1);
```

which is based on the paper: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~mobile/Papers/2014ICRA_maddern.pdf

I tried normalized with respect to min/max of the whole dataset, but it did not work and I got weird results. How can I normalize the images by keeping the images consistent after processing?

Comment: Create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do min/max function in MATLAB, it only does it in one dimension. So if you have a 256x256 image, when you do min(image), you get a 1x256 vector. And when you divide this you are doing (256x256)/(1x256) = 256x1

To fix this, you'll want to do min(min(image))

Comment: No, actually I used `max(I_old(:))` and `min(I_old(:))` and I have corrected my question now. Thank you.

Comment: This is the equation they used in the paper, is there a reason you changed it?
    'function [ ii_image ] = ...

    RGB2IlluminationInvariant( image, alpha )

    ii_image = 0.5 + log(image(:,:,2)) - ...

    alpha*log(image(:,:,3)) - ...

    (1-alpha)*log(image(:,:,1));'

Comment: Yes. I added 1 to each channel in order to avoid `-Inf` where `log(0) = -Inf`